# Appending numpy array without flattening

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

Let's say I have three arrays like this:

`Total = [], A = [1,2,3]` and `B = [4,5,6]`.

When I use `Total = np.append(Total,A)` it gives me: `[1,2,3]`

And when I use `Total = np.append(Total,B)` it gives me: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

What I want after the second append is: `Total = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`.

Comment: Does `np.vstack((A, B))` do what you're after?

Comment: @JonClements No, because the dimensions don't match.

Comment: Well - they do in your example? Could you provide a real use case where they don't and what output you expect from a 2D array where the dimensions don't match?

Comment: It almost looks like you're not using numpy here and just want `total = [A, B]` ?

Comment: Don't use `np.appwnd` without reading its docs.  Better yet don't use it at all.  And don't `stack` iteratively. `vstack` a list of all items once.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stack them?

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]

Total = np.vstack((A,B))    
print(Total)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

**OR**

just add the lists:

```
T = [A] + [B]    
print(T)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])

np.vstack([a, b])
np.stack([a, b], axis=0)
np.c_[a, b].T
np.concatenate([a[np.newaxis], b[np.newaxis]])
```